# Can win 32 console C++ application compiled in Visual Studio 2013 be run in Mono under Linux?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, mono

I'm working on a C++ project in Visual Studio 2013 which is a console app and produces exe file, which I want to run under Linux - Ubuntu. I already tried with wine and the app is working fine , but my goal is to run it with mono . Any ideas how can I achieve this run ?

Answer (score 0):

Mono doesn't execute binary C++ applications, it executes [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) applications. In effect, Mono acts as a Free Software [Common Language Runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) and set of development tools. As such, the Mono CLR is a virtual-machine, similar to the JRE, and isn't responsible for executing binary compiled applications.

I'm not certain why you would need to run this with Mono instead of Wine, but if it works with Wine I would imagine you could stick to that. Another option may be to write your C++ code in such a way as to be compilable on any platform, than you can simply compile the C++ program using GCC on GNU/Linux. This way it will run as a native GNU/Linux program which would be the fastest executable time. Another option is to call C++ precompiled code from the Mono Runtime using [CppSharp](https://github.com/mono/cppsharp).

Comment: There are really three possible solutions: generally, I would prefer the one you suggest, writing the program in portable C++, and compiling for each platform.  Alternatively, there's what he's doing (which seems to me the worst solution, _if_ you want to run under Unix).  Finally, he can compile in his program as CLR under Windows, and use `mono`.  This has the advantage that he only has to compile on one platform, and the disadvantage that he can't really test the program, because he doesn't know where it might run.